# 'Day' as a preposition

Tags: grammar, prepositions

'The next day, they woke up early to find that it had disappeared.'

Does 'day' function as a preposition here? That is, should the above sentence not read '*On* the next day...'?

Comment: Predictable prepositions, like _on_ for days, are often omitted. And _day_ does not 'act as a preposition'.

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence, *the next day* is an **adjunct of temporal location** which is realized by a **noun phrase** (NP).

True, adjuncts of temporal location are *very often* realized by preposition phrases (PPs), but certainly not always.

In your sentence, either a PP or an NP would work, but that is not always so. Consider, for example,

[1]  ***Last night,** I came home late.*

Here *last night* is also an NP. But in this case, there is no preposition that can be attached to it to convert it to a PP such that the meaning remains the same.

Comment: Doesn't CGEL subscribe to 'determiner phrases'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth They call it *determinative phrase* (DP). Some of their examples of DPs include ***not many** people saw her leave, **almost all** copies were lost,* and ***at least ten** people were killed.* The word *last* in *last night* is indeed a determinative (p. 356n): 'We might also include [in the category of determinatives] *last* and *next* as used in temporal deictic expressions such as *last week, next year,* etc., where they contrast with the central determinative *this*.' But *last night* as a whole is an NP.